# Invalid Arguments when Adding a row to the DB -

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am currently having a issue trying to add a row to the DB... This is a windows form application on visual studio 2013... I have a entities folder with my TargetCells table uploaded...

I also tried to take everything out of the object I am creating and just do the first line.. so that I was only passing in 1 item with the object, and it still doesn't like that... so I don't think its the way my model is being packed/object created....

My Error:

> The best overloaded method match for '`System.Data.Entity.DbSet<AssemblyTargets.Entities.TargetCells>.Add(AssemblyTargets.Entities.TargetCells)`' has some invalid arguments

In my constructor: (The line db.TargetCells.Add(cellModel) is where my error is occuring, I put the stars around it to help you find it.. )

```
        Cell1Model cellModel = new Cell1Model
        {
            cell = 1,
            DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(today),
            customerdemand = Convert.ToInt32(txtCusDemand.Text),
            StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTeamStart.Text),
            Break1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtBreak1Time.Text),
            Break2 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtBreak2Time.Text),
            Break3 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtBreak3Time.Text),
            TimeforBreak1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtBreak1.Text),
            TimeforBreak2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtBreak2.Text),
            Timeforbreak3 = Convert.ToInt32(txtBreak3.Text),
            Lunch = Convert.ToDateTime(txtLunch1Time.Text),
            TimeforLunch = Convert.ToInt32(txtLunchBreak.Text)
        };


        // Add the new object to the TargetCells collection.

        ***db.TargetCells.Add(cellModel);***


        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges(cellModel);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            // Make some adjustments. 
            // ... 
            // Try again.
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

My Model Looks Like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AssemblyTargets.Models;
using AssemblyTargets.Entities;


namespace AssemblyTargets.Models
{
class Cell1Model
{
    public int recid { get; set; }
    public int? cell { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTime { get; set; }
    public int? customerdemand { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Break1 { get; set; }
    public int? TimeforBreak1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Break2 { get; set; }
    public int? TimeforBreak2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Break3 { get; set; }
    public int? Timeforbreak3 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Lunch { get; set; }
    public int? TimeforLunch { get; set; }
}
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The exception gives you the answer - you're trying to add a `CellModel` and the method wants a `AssemblyTargets.Entities.TargetCells` instance.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Can you post your TargetCells design?

Comment: Charles Mager was correct, I was using my Cell1Model, when I should have been using TargetCells